# Delete ClusterRoleBinding and Namespace from process running in same Namespace in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I create a `Namespace` on a kube cluster and install my app within that Namespace. The app sends regular heartbeat requests to the server and if it gets a *"remove yourself"* response from the server, it deletes itself by calling delete on the entire kube Namespace. I also give the app cluster wide access by creating a `ClusterRoleBinding`, making a `ServiceAccount` subject to the `ClusterRoleBinding` and running the pod with this `ServiceAccount`.

The problem is that I want to remove the `ClusterRoleBinding` as part of app's self removal process (if that's possible).  If I remove the `ClusterRoleBinding` before then the app won't be able to issue a delete on the `Namespace` so it seems like a chicken-and-egg problem. Is there a way to do this?

This is what I have already tried to no avail:

- Added a PreStop handler in the app container. So now when the app calls delete on the entire Namespace, kube calls this handler before killing the container. In this PreStop handler if I sleep for more than 5 sec before calling delete on `ClusterRoleBinding` I get *"Unauthorized"* response back from kubernetes.
- This lead me to think that maybe the `ServiceAccount` that's linked to the `ClusterRoleBinding` gets deleted before the app has had a chance to delete the `ClusterRoleBinding` in the PreStop handler. So to test this, before issuing delete on the Namespace I add a finalizer to the `ServiceAccount`, then in the PreStop handler I wait for 5 sec, issue delete on the `ClusterRoleBinding` *(again get "Unauthorized" error back),* then I get the `ServiceAccount` object by name *(get "Unauthorized" error back)*, remove the finalizer from the `ServiceAccount` *(get error "error="finalizer doesn't exist for object ''")* because it can't remove the finalizer on an empty object. When I use kubectl I find that the `ServiceAccount` exists but is in *"Terminating"* state as expected with the finalizer still set.

**Does kube revoke access when `ServiceAccount` is in `"Terminating"` state even though its not yet hard deleted?**

**Is there a way to remove the `ClusterRoleBinding` and the `Namespace` from the same process that is running in the `Namespace` that needs to be deleted? (Given that the `ClusterRoleBinding` we want to remove gives the app permission to delete the `Namespace` in the first place)**

Any help would be much appreciated!

The YAML definitions for `ClusterRoleBinding` and `ServiceAccount` are as below:

```yaml
### ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    name: xyz-myapp-cluster-admin
roleRef:
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: ClusterRole
    name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: xyz
  namespace: xyz-myapp

### ServiceAccount
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
    creationTimestamp: null
    name: xyz
    namespace: xyz-myapp
```

Relevant application logs:

```
time="2020-02-18T16:08:33Z" level=info msg="App instructed to remove itself"
time="2020-02-18T16:08:33Z" level=info msg="Created finalizer 'xyz.myapp.com/my-finalizer' on ServiceAccount"
time="2020-02-18T16:08:33Z" level=info msg="Called delete on Namespace"
time="2020-02-18T16:08:38Z" level=info msg="PreStop handler called"
time="2020-02-18T16:08:38Z" level=info msg="----- sleeping for 5 sec -----"
time="2020-02-18T16:08:43Z" level=info msg="Deleting ClusterRoleBinding"
time="2020-02-18T16:08:43Z" level=warning msg="Failed to delete ClusterRoleBinding" error="Unexpected error removing ClusterRolebinding: Unauthorized"
time="2020-02-18T16:08:43Z" level=warning msg="Failed to get ServiceAccount" error=Unauthorized
time="2020-02-18T16:08:43Z" level=warning msg="Failed to remove finalizer from ServiceAccount" error="finalizer 'xyz.myapp.com/my-finalizer' doesn't exist for object ''"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging through kubernetes documentation, the most reliable way I found to do this is:

1. When the app gets a *"remove yourself"* response back from server it makes the `ClusterRoleBinding` the owner of the `Namespace` the app runs in.
2. This can be done by adding `ClusterRoleBinding` under Namespace's `medatadata.owerReferences` using patch.
3. Once `ClusterRoleBinding` is successfully added as an owner for `Namespace`, then the app can call delete on the `ClusterRoleBinding` using `DeletePropagationBackground`.

Below is an example of how a patch that adds a `ClusterRoleBinding` to `ownerReferences` of a `Namespace` can be applied (in Golang).

```golang
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    v1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    rbacv1 "k8s.io/api/rbac/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

type ownerReferencePatch struct {
    Op    string                  `json:"op"`
    Path  string                  `json:"path"`
    Value []metav1.OwnerReference `json:"value"`
}

func AddClusterRoleBindingOwnerReferenceToNamespace(client kubernetes.Interface, crb *rbacv1.ClusterRoleBinding, ns *v1.Namespace) (*v1.Namespace, error) {
    patch, err := json.Marshal([]ownerReferencePatch{
        {
            Op:   "add",
            Path: "/metadata/ownerReferences",
            Value: []metav1.OwnerReference{
                {
                    APIVersion:         crb.RoleRef.APIGroup,
                    BlockOwnerDeletion: func(in bool) *bool {return &in}(true),
                    Kind:               "ClusterRoleBinding",
                    Name:               crb.GetName(),
                    UID:                crb.GetUID(),
                },
            },
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return client.CoreV1().Namespaces().Patch(ns.GetName(), types.JSONPatchType, patch)
}
```

Comment: Nicely found! This is a link to the [k8s docs about the ownerReferences](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/)